# How can we Check Uniqueness in Informatica CDQ without Aggregator (Active Transformation), so it can be applied in Rule Specification

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, iics, iics-di

How can we Check Uniqueness in Informatica CDQ without Aggregator (Active Transformation), while using Active Transformations like Aggregator or Sorter, its throwing the error that "The mapplet is active. Only passive mapplets can be added in Rule Specification."  How can we apply the uniqueness in Rule Specification?

How can we Check Uniqueness in Informatica CDQ without Aggregator (Active Transformation), so it can be applied in Rule Specification .

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to take advantage of the properties of `Lookup Transformation` with `Dynamic Cache` enabled. Once you configure the `Dynamic Cache` there is a `NewLookupRow` port added to the transformation output. As mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/data-integration/current-version/transformations/lookup-transformation/dynamic-lookup-cache/dynamic-cache-updates.html) it will tell you if the row is a duplicate, whenever it's different then 1:

```
NewLookupRow Value
0: Mapping task does not update or insert the row in the cache.
1: Mapping task inserts the row into the cache.
2: Mapping task updates the row in the cache.
```